# CSS Forms/Input Maniuplation

Tags: html, css, forms, input, focus

```
input:required{
    background-color:#f00;
}

input:required label{
   color: #FF3434;
}
```

I have the above CSS code currently for my form,

I want to be able to make the label red when the field is required. My input field is:

```
<label for="frmComTelephone">Telephone</label>  
<input type="number" name="Telephone" id="frmComTelephone"/>

<label for="frmIn1IncinTime">Time</label>   
<input type="text" name="Incident Time" id="frmIn1IncinTime" required="required"/><br>
```

But that CSS isn't working how do I solve this?

2ND problem is I have the following CSS:

```
input:focus 
{ 
    background-color:yellow;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="date"],input[type="time"],input[type="number"],textarea,select
{
border-radius:5px;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #C6C6C6; 
height:41px;
background-color: #FF3434;
width: 100%;

}
```

But when the item is focused it doesn't change to yellow, if i remove "background-color: #FF3434;" it turns yellow on focus?

Is what I am doing not able to be done? Or am I going about this wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What browser are you using? I dont believe `:required` is cross browser compatiable, at least for now

Comment: Chrome for testing and publishing to blackberry webworks , where required works, Also thank you for pointing that out

Comment: to 1st: I cannot see any required-attribute in your html-code.

Comment: Hello, i have another feild its edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1:**

```
input:required label{
   color: #FF3434;
}
```

This won't work because the `label` is not a child of the `input`. They're siblings. To solve that you have to create a class and attach it to your label:

```
label.required { color: #FF3434; }
<label for="frmComTelephone" class="required">Telephone</label>
```

**Issue 2:**

Try this:

```
input:focus,
textarea:focus,
select:focus
{ background-color: yellow !important; }
```

...

**UPDATE**

If you're more comfortable without using `!important` then try this:

```
input[type="text"]:focus, 
input[type="date"]:focus,
input[type="time"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
textarea:focus,
select:focus
{ background-color: yellow }
```

***OR***

if you have an `id` on your form this will also work

```
#formID input:focus,
#formID textarea:focus,
#formID select:focus
{ background-color: yellow }
```

Comment: Please don't use `!important`, fix the specifity/order instead.

Comment: @pixelistik I think using `!important` isn't always an awful practice, but got your point and updated with possible solutions without it

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `input:focus` rule behind the `input[type="number"]` rule or use `input[type="number"]:focus`.

Otherwise its overwritten by `input[type="number"]` as it's more specific.

Comment: textarea:focus,select:focus  this doesn't seem to work when doing where your saying, and the required is defined like this  textarea:required{background-color:#f00;} 
 select:required{background-color:#f00;}

Comment: My CSS was ordered wrong , your correct it works fine also you on focus on my check boxes it doesnt do anything to them how would i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem 2:

CSS selectors by attribute, like `input[type="number"]` and pseudo-elements like `:focus` have equal specifity. This means that your `input:focus` rule gets overridden by the following `input[type="number"]` background.

There are two ways to fix this:

Higher specifity in the first selector:

```
form input:focus 
{ 
    background-color:yellow;
}

input[type="text"]
{
    background-color: #FF3434;
}
```

Better: Correct rule order, more important one comes second

```
input[type="text"]
{
    background-color: #FF3434;
}

form input:focus 
{ 
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

CSS specifity seems hard, but it's worth understanding it properly. There are a lot of resources about it, try this introduction: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Thank you, do you have idea of the best way to stlye a checkbox on focus? As nothing nice seems to get done to it...